# How do I enable key repeat on iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am working on a project in iOS and would like to enable key repeat. I have done quite a bit of looking around and have failed to come up with any option like that (which surprises me quite a bit, actually).

Is there a way to enable key repeat on an iOS device?

Comment: Not possible from the screen keyboard, but maybe from a wireless keyboard?  I can't test it myself...

Comment: How to solve this problem? I have same problem

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here are inaccurate. The correct answer is "sort of"

@MichaelGoerz Comment is correct. There seems to be a bug in iOS where key repeat only works for certain keys instead of all keys as expected. For example backspace will repeat per your settings but "w" won't. I recommend filing a bug report with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com in an effort to prod them to fix this. This bug is highly irritating especially when using remote desktop tools where holding down a key might be required.

I occurred to me that this may also be by design, an attempt by Apple to be "helpful" by only allowing the most commonly used repeating keys. Due to the fact that the Settings->General->Accessibility->Keyboard->Key Repeat menu makes no mention of this I am treating it as a bug.

Comment: iPads don't have this problem when using an "official" Apple ("folio") keyboard.  It's only broken when using a Bluetooth keyboard (I have both keyboard types at the moment for test purposes).  So it's probably just another scenario where Apple is intentionally crippling non-apple products in order to make their own stuff look better and drive people the "official" accessories. Though, I suppose it _could_ just be a bug when in Bluetooth mode.  Not one that they will likely fix, however...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, iOS allows key repeat for Bluetooth keyboards, and you can even [change the key repeat rate](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29021230#29021230) as follows (quoting LucaMarconato):

> If you go in Settings->General->Accessibility->Keyboard->Key Repeat
>   you can set the Key Repeat Interval to 0,03 seconds (the minumum
>   allowed).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for "normal" keys, only  for arrow keys, space, and delete

Comment: @MichaelGoerz Is correct. There is a bug in iOS or a really terrible design choice.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is a bug right now and happens with Magic Keyboards as well as other Bluetooth keyboards (there is no keyboard discrimination).

It looks like the keys a-z, A-Z and 0-9 don't repeat. However, *all* other keys seem to work fine (including the symbols above the numbers on a conventional QWERTY keyboard).

I have tested this on an iPad Air 3rd gen and iPad Air 5th gen with the Magic Keyboard and some other 3rd party Bluetooth keyboard.

I contacted Apple support who got in touch with the engineering team responsible for this. They confirmed from them that it is a bug and they're aware of it. They said they would try their best to escalate it, otherwise cannot guarantee that it's fixed.
Apple is pretty opaque with this kind of thing and they were not willing to provide an issue to track online etc.
Although the lack of transparency is not ideal I do think we should appreciate that they acknowledge this is a bug as opposed to shrugging it off as expected behavior. Bugs happen!

I assume like any engineering team, this can be reprioritized if management decides this is more important. I would suggest contacting Apple to try to add to the pressure, or better yet, find someone you know that blogs about tech and have them do a little excerpt about the newest iPad and this odd behavior (maybe even compare it to any other tablet that doesn't have this bug).

If I find an improvement, I'll try to update this post. Hope this helps.

Comment: MacOS has not had key repeat since 2011, though you can turn it on via a terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

## No.*

*At least not for the software keyboard. I believe that an external (USB or BlueTooth) keyboard will repeat such keys.

Comment: The software keyboard interprets a long press as an attempt to choose an alternate character, i.e. holding down "a" gives you options for: ã å ā à á â ä æ.

Comment: I think hardware keyboards also produce the pop-up accent menue via long press starting with iOS 16.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of. I needed to repeat the * for separation of text. I was able to create a keyboard shortcut to place a line of stars by double tapping the * key. Worked for me, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the others: by default, the iOS settings only allows auto-repeat for non-alphanumeric characters (everything, except letters and numbers). But you can make it work with alphanumeric characters using `wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior`. What I did was:

```swift
for key in 0x061...0x079 { // all 26 lowercase roman letters
    let K = Unicode.Scalar(key)!
    let key = UIKeyCommand(input: "\(K)", modifierFlags: [],  action: #selector(insertKey))
    key.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior = true
    basicKeyCommands.append(key)
    let keyS = UIKeyCommand(input: "\(K)", modifierFlags: .shift,  action: #selector(insertKey))
    keyS.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior = true
    basicKeyCommands.append(keyS)
}
```

This gives me self-repeating keys for all lowercase and uppercase letters. If you want self-repeating keys for numbers, you need to be more careful: on many non-English keyboards, the numbers are not the default character for the key (you need to type shift to get the number, and you have characters `&` or `ç` without shift). So the previous approach won't work. I used a similar approach, but only for English keyboards:

```swift
if let keyboardLanguage = self.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage {
    if keyboardLanguage.hasPrefix("en") {
        for key in 0x030...0x039 { // all 10 numbers
            let K = Unicode.Scalar(key)!
            let key = UIKeyCommand(input: "\(K)", modifierFlags: [],  action: #selector(insertKey))
            key.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior = true
            basicKeyCommands.append(key)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if your application users can switch to languages with multi-character input (Chinese, Japanese, Hindi-transliteration), you need to deactivate these keyboard shortcuts specifically for these:

```swift
if let keyboardLanguage = self.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage {
    if (!keyboardLanguage.hasPrefix("hi") && !keyboardLanguage.hasPrefix("zh") && !keyboardLanguage.hasPrefix("ja")) {
        // Insert here the first code snipet.
    }
}
```

This `key.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior` setting is available on iOS 15 and above.

Comment: Can you explain how someone with a non-jailbroken device would use your code?

Comment: That code is for app developers who want to enable auto-repeat in their apps. There is no way for a standard user to enable auto-repeat, sorry.